# iOS TvOS Tab Bar with Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, apple-tv

I am working on an Apple Tv app which main screen is a tab bar. In the first tab I have a `UINavigationController` which view controller has a collection view. When select a cell in the collection view I launch a show segue to another view controller but the navigation bar isn't shown. I've checked that the "Shows navigation bar" is selected in the navigation controller... It is not possible to have a navigation controller inside a tab bar controller in an Apple Tv App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is easy, there is no "navigation bar" as such... due to the "back" button in a navigation controller is the "Menu" button in the remote, so there is no need to show the navigation bar with the back button

Comment: But if I want to put another button at right side of navigation bar then what should I do, can u please tell me ?